# Given the orthonormal base of a given vector, find the coordinates of that vector on another base

Tags: vectors

> In an orthonormal base, the coordinates of the vector $\vec{v}=(2,-5)$. Find the coordinates of $\vec{v}$ on the base $B=((1,-1),(0,-1))$

**Attempt.** Actually not 100% sure on what the intuition of a base in general is, I'm trying to understand it through exercises. Anyways, my attempt:

Any base $B$ is defined as $B=a\vec{x}+b\vec{y}$ where $a$ and $b$ are constants. If the base is orthonormal, it means the vectors that form that base form 90 degrees and have a length of 1. I related this base to the usual $\hat{i}$ and $\hat{j}$ one. On any case, I did: $$\vec{v}=a\hat{i}+b\hat{j}$$ and found $a=2$ and $b=-5$. The new base will have the same constants $a$ and $b$? Don't know at all if this method is valid but here it is: the new base is $B'=a(1,-1)+b(0,-1)$ and as we know $a=2$ and $v=-5$, $\vec{v}$ will be this? $$\vec{v}=2(1,-1)-5(0,-1)=(2,3)$$ which actually gives the right answer in the book but I'm afraid the procedure is bad or if I feel like I have some concepts wrong about bases.

Answer (score 1):

2 ways to do this.

One is to say $e_1 = (1,-1), e_2 = (0,-1)$  These are our basis vectors of $B.$

There exists some combination basis vectors such that $a e_1 + b e_2 = v = (2,-5)$

This provides a system of equations to solve.

$(a,-a) + (0,-b) = (a, -a-b) = (2,-5)\\
a = 2\\
-a-b = -5\\
a = 2, b = 3$

And, this is probably how your Prof. expects you do to solve this.

But, this is worth knowing.

$B = \begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\-1&-1 \end {bmatrix}$

$Bu$ will take a vector $u$ represented in the basis $B$ and translate it to the standard basis.

That means that $B^{-1}v$ will take a vector $v$ in the standard basis and represent it in terms of the basis $B$

The reason the method you use above gives the right answer is that in this case $B^{-1} = B$

Comment: Okay but some things: is my approach incorrect methodically? also, you didn't use at all the fact that the first base was orthonormal on the question, did you? And most importantly, what's the intuition behind equating the vector given from another completely different base into a new base? Doesn't the new vector change from base to base? Maybe I just lack of understanding on what the base is, and the *coordinates* that they ask, are those coordinates $a$ and $b$? or $\vec{v}=(2,3)$?